# How to log limitation and rotation to ROS2

Tags: logging, log-rotation, ros2

I want to apply limitation to the size, number and rotation of log files that will be saved under `.ros/log`. People mentioned this issue [here](https://answers.ros.org/question/229966/does-ros-have-rolling-log-files-ability-to-limit-total-size/#:%7E:text=log%20limited%20to%20100MB%20and,seems%20to%20extend%20%2F%20complete%20this.) but I could not find any example/instruction for that so any idea/suggestion/sample would help. The target ROS version is ROS2 Eloquent.